# How to Underline/Bold/Color words in string (javascript)

Tags: javascript

My simple program will take an input of a phrase like: One, `____`, Three, Four, `____`, and then get your input for each blank and create the new phrase with the blanks filled in. For example, I would input two, then four. The code would then output the phrase: One, Two, Three, Four, Five. I want the program to put some sort of emphasis on the words given to it, like an underline, bold, or color.

```
var Que = prompt("Insert your completion question");
var Leng = Que.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= Leng; i+=1){
  if (Que.substring(i,i + 4) === "____"){
      var newword = prompt(Que.substring(0, i + 4));
      Que.replace("____", newword);
      if (newword.length !== 4){
          var i = newword.length - 4 + i;
      }
  }
}
console.log(Que);
```

Comment: Strings are just text; it doesn't make sense to have a bold string.  Are you asking how to write HTML tags?

Comment: You need to split your text into multiple `<span>...</span>` blocks. Then you can give each span a different style.